# Filtering data with NULL in QGIS

Tags: filter, null

Working with QGIS Zanzibar. I have a data set where many values are NULL (or blank), I wish to filter the data to show only those with NULL. In the query builder I use "FieldName" = NULL, but this removes ALL the data... Why. The data I'm trying to filter on is a date.

Comment: There is a small trick `"FieldName" IS NULL`

Comment: Many thanks.. I knew there was a trick to solve this one.

Comment: And the inverse then is `"FieldName" IS NOT NULL`. It's because NULL is a state not a value.

Comment: Just like Excel.. it too can't handle NULL/Blank very well.. Thanks for the tip "NULL is a state not a value"